# Stripe and validate payments synchronously

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe in my site and I have the following question. I have read in the official documentation that is needed to use Payment Intents / Checkout to accomplish with 3d secure payments but my doubt is: How can I validate a payment made through this methods in a synchronous way to allow customers to instant download a product without waiting to the webhook call?

I am using Symfony to build the front and the back of the system.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wait for a webhook to get confirmation that a payment was successful. `stripe.handleCardPayment` will immediately tell you if the payment was successful or not. See the `then` promise fulfillment [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#completing-payment).

If you're using new Checkouts, users will be directed to your payment success page on completion of payment. A webhook is sent to inform you of the payment completion in case the user closes the browser or tab before the redirect can happen.